# flexbox behaves differenly on iOS/android

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo

I noticed react-native renders flexbox in different ways across the platforms.
This is what I want to get (Which also I get in android)
https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/3959528/64351746a0c4eca7f83c2bc981dad55a

So simply an image and some text centered on the screen vertically and horizontally, and some text on the bottom of the screen.
**In iOS I cannot see the text "center text"**

You can reproduce the behavior here
https://snack.expo.io/@alfredopacino/flexbox-ios-android
Does anyone have a solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a flexbox issue. This issue generates because of react native component working differently in both platforms. In Ios react native component default padding is 0.

**In Android Textinput and Text taking by default some padding but in IOS by default padding of this component is zero(0)**

This issue may solve in near future by react native team .

If you add padding into you style text i will work like charm

```
<Text 
  style={{padding:Platform.OS==='ios'?15:0,
 }}>
Center text
</Text>
```

Update Answer

https://snack.expo.io/@vishal7008/flexbox-ios-android

Comment: it seems the padding is not the only difference, I updated the snack with your solution which highlights an issue in case of longer text

Comment: You Means text is not into center??

Comment: nop, just the first row is visible, you can see in the snack

Comment: @alfredopacino please check snack i update my answer. You have add one extra view so remove it

Comment: **remove this** **<View>** **remove this**    <View style={{background:"red",flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column',alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>        <Image style={{width: 50, height: 50}} source={{uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/assets/favicon.png'}}        />        <Text style={{textAlign:"center",padding:Platform.OS==='ios'?15:0}}>         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,{"\n"}consectetur adipiscing elit. id ut augue.        </Text>       </View>     **remove this**  **</View>**  **remove this**

Comment: Ok, it taken me a while to get what's your solution :) You simply put the bottom View outside the "main" column flexbox..the result is the center View is not perfectly vertically centered, but I guess there is no simple and better solution

Comment: Happy coding dude

Answer (score 1):

Add some height into that it will work

```
<Text style={{height:50}}>
    Center text
</Text>
```

Comment: I simplified the example that text is dynamic and multilanguage, I cannot set a fixed height

Comment: How dynamic they could be? what exactly you want to do?

Comment: Actually your solution seems to work, fixing height doesn't affect the bottom View

Comment: Happy to help you

Comment: wait, it doesn't affect the bottom View but affects the center View, it is not perfectly centered anymore, there is no better solution?